# Tensorflow: iterating over a Tensor for embedding lookup?

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose I have a matrix of N users, and each user is associated with a vector of words (translated to integers).  So for example for N = 2 I'd have:

```
user 0 corresponds to words['20','56']

user 1 corresponds to words ['58','10','105']
```

So I have a list

```
user_words = [['20','56'],['58','10','105']]
```

Suppose further I created a 100-column embedding matrix (word_emb) for these words.  I'd like to look up the (mean) embeddings of each of the user vectors and create a new Tensor, whose shape I would expect to be [2,100].  I tried doing this:

```
word_vec = []
for word_sequence_i in tf.map_fn(lambda x: x, user_words):
    all_word_vecs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(word_emb, word_sequence_i)
    word_vec.append( tf.reduce_mean(all_word_vecs, 1))
```

But this gives me an error:

```
TypeError: `Tensor` objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use `tf.map_fn`.
```

I thought I already was using tf.map_fn above!  So what is Tensorflow complaining about?  Is there even a way to do what I am trying to do?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

`tf.map_fn` returns a `Tensor` object itself, which is a symbolic reference to a value that will be computed at `Session.run()` time. You can see this with `type(tf.map_fn(lambda x: x, user_words))`. So, it's the iteration implied in `for word_sequence_i in tf.map_fn(...)` that is generating the error.

Perhaps what you're looking for is something like:

```
all_word_vecs = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.nn.embedding_lookup(word_emb, x), user_words)
word_vec = tf.reduce_mean(all_word_vecs, axis=1)
```

On a related note, if this distinction between graph construction and execution is getting bothersome, you might want to give TensorFlow's eager execution a spin. See [getting started](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/eager) and [the programmer's guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks ash, I tried that but unfortunately that didn't work because tf.map_fn wants two arguments.  I see where you are going with this but not sure how to code it up so that tf.reduce_mean is applied within tf.map_fn to each element of user_words?

Comment: Tweaked the answer slightly, to fix the `tf.map_fn` call. As to your other point, the way I look at it is that every occurrence of the `for` loop can be replaced by a `tf.map_fn`. So, to reduce, you'd do something like `tf.map_fn(reduce_mean, tf.map_fn(embedding_lookup, user_words))` or something along those lines. Hope that help.